# Wrong listeners for FIRDatabaseReference fired

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

According to the documentation of Firebase [image: FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded :This event is triggered once for each existing child and then again every time a new child is added to the specified path.]

`FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded :This event is triggered once for each existing child and then again every time a new child is added to the specified path.`

but it is even triggered when i am updating a child at specified node using method `updateChildValues`

[updateChildValues Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#update_specific_fields)

MY CODE :

```
[_followersReference observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded
                            withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
                               //increment the badge here
                                //add in local DB
                                //can fire a local notification
                                RCFollowerFireBaseModel *remoteFollower = [RCFollowerFireBaseModel parseDictionary:snapshot.value];
                                GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:remoteFollower.location.coordinate];
                                marker.title = remoteFollower.name;
                                marker.snippet = remoteFollower.time;
                                marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;
                                marker.map = self.mapView;

                            }
                      withCancelBlock:^(NSError * _Nonnull error) {

                      }];

[_followersReference observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeChildRemoved
                            withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
                               //decrement the badge here
                                //remove followers

                                NSLog(@"%@",snapshot);
                            }
                      withCancelBlock:^(NSError * _Nonnull error) {

                      }];


[_followersReference observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeChildChanged
                            withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
                                //update the marker with the updated coordinates here
                                //can apply 
                            }
                      withCancelBlock:^(NSError * _Nonnull error) {

                      }];
```

My problem is FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded should not get triggered when i am updating a child at the `_followerReference` rather FIRDataEventTypeChildChanged should be triggered but updating child at `_followerReference` triggers both `FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded` and `FIRDataEventTypeChildChanged`.

Am i doing something wrong or it is a bug in Firebase?

Comment: None of your code is triggering any changes, to it's hard to say what you're seeing. Please provide the [minimal complete code that is needed to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This will include the JSON (as text, no screenshot) at the location you're reading/modifying, the code of the listener that is causing problems and the code that changes a value.

Comment: Frank the answer provided luckily solved my issue btw thanks for the edit i'll take care for the minimal code needed to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a bug ,i encountered the same problem.
Make sure you are not calling this method recursively

`- (FIRDatabaseHandle)observeEventType:(FIRDataEventType)eventType withBlock:(void (^)(FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot))block withCancelBlock:(nullable void (^)(NSError* error))cancelBlock;`

Comment: This method was NSTimer selector being called every 30 seconds. removing that fixed my problem Thank you.